# Jenkins CI Job Workspace custom changes

Tags: java, maven, svn, jboss, jenkins

I have setup a CI environment for deploying to dev using Jenkins/Maven/SVN. For the deployment to Jboss Eap server, I am using JBoss as maven plugin. Since the project teams does not have the plugin for this the jboss-as:deploy in the respective poms, once I create the job in Jenkins and a local workspace gets created for the project, I manually update the pom.xml with the plugin and the server configuration. Is there any way to automate this process? I dont have the option to ask all project teams to commit the plugin in the pom file. Issues i am facing.

1. Project teams commit a change at the same line number where I added the jboss as dependency in the pom, caused a svn merge conflict in my Jenkins local workspace and the build fails since pom is corrupted.
2. For every job, I have to manually update the POM in the Jenkins workspace.
3. If I have to deploy a project to multiple app servers, I have to create multiple jobs.

Can anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: The obvious question is, why can't the project teams add the JBoss plugin to their POMs ?  You're going to have a whole stack of work to get around this.

Comment: We cant enforce anything on the project team. Since mine is an automation team, I am not supposed to ask the project teams for any changes to incorporate CI. Also, for multiple server deployment, I have to hardcode the hostname, port and credentials for each server. So i create multiple jobs.

Comment: Could you suggest a workaround?

Comment: I don't want to sound glib, but this is really a cultural issue.  You can't achieve true continuous integration if your project and automation teams have process barriers between them.  So sorry, but I don't have a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @gareth_bowles. I have asked all the teams to put in the config in pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another `distribution-component` and keep it separately, e.g. as a component or module. I would update inside its `pom.xml` the change you mentioned and just support two projects - the developers' one and the one used for other purposes.